# Cannot resolve symbol ItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

i got this error when i extends **ItemizedOverlay** on Activity. How can i resolve this error ? can any one help me out here.

Comment: Are you using Google Maps v1 or v2? ItemizedOverlay is no longer available in Google Maps v2.

Comment: @ziem  yes i am using google Maps v2. How can i resolve ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: drop  marker and get  latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0):

`ItemizedOverlay` is no longer available in Google Maps v2.

If you would like to display marker on a map you can user `Marker` class. You can create `Marker` object using [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions).

I'm attaching the simplest example:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(52.2330653, 20.9211106))
            .title("Warsaw"));
}
```

In addition I recommend reading [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) and [Markers section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker).

You can [make a marker draggable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#make_a_marker_draggable) using:

```
MarkerOptions.draggable(boolean)
Marker.setDraggable(boolean)
```

You can also attach marker drag listener, you can find more [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#marker_drag_events).

Comment: Thanks , but ItemizedOverlay used to drop pin marker in MapView. 
The same thing i want to do in V2. (Dropping pin`s in Mapview)

Comment: I added how to make a marker draggable to my answer. If you would like to drop marker you can use `GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener` and add it to map.